# Integration of sqrt Sin x dx

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \sqrt{\sin x}\ \text dx$$

I asked my teachers and they said that this integration is pretty next level and will be taught in college.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you ever heard of elliptic integrals?

Comment: The answer involves the elliptic integral of the second kind. I think your teacher may not be entirely correct... I'd be surprised if that was covered in a standard undergrad curriculum. At least in the states.

Comment: @graydad actually it's a bit complicated because I'm in a dummy school. Do you have the solution?

Comment: @Dmoreno yep but only online, haven't been taught yet.

Comment: @ParasThakur I'm confused by your comment; I'm suggesting that I think your teacher is wrong. I think this integral is beyond (a normal) undergraduate curriculum. Not sure how you being in a "dummy" school is related

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: @graydad this is covered in high schools in India

Answer (score 8):

Your integral may be expressed in terms of an incomplete elliptic integral, a Legendre integral, one may prove that

> $$
> \int_0^x \sqrt{\sin t}\ \text dt=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2-2 \text{EllipticE}\left[\frac{1}{4} (\pi -2 x),2\right],\quad 0\leq x \leq \pi,
> $$

where $\text{EllipticE}\left[\phi,m\right]$ is a special function studied by Legendre and you will find many of its properties [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2).

Comment: Thank you for your response but can't it be solved in a simpler way?

Comment: @ParasThakur Define $F(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{\sin t}\,dt$.  By the fundamental theorem of calculus, this is an antiderivative.  (Remember: every function has an integral.  Whether you can write it using more elementary functions is another matter, and for this particular integral you will need something like one of the mentioned special functions.)

Comment: @Paras, unfortunately the antiderivative of $f(t)=\sqrt{\sin t}$ can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @Kyle, what you mean by "every function has an integral"?

Comment: @luka5z I missed the word "continuous." I'm defining "integral" (i.e., "indefinite integral") of $f$ as a function $F$ which can be used to compute definite integrals by $\int_a^bf(t)\,dt=F(b)-F(a)$.  In fact, (supposing $0$ is in the connected component of the domain you care about), $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ is sufficient, and by the FTC this is also an antiderivative of $f$ if you want that property.  This is what I mean by every [continuous] function having an integral.

Comment: @Kyle, all good now

Answer (score 5):

Given $\displaystyle \int\sqrt{\sin x}\;dx$

Let $\displaystyle \sin x = t^2\Leftrightarrow \cos xdx = 2tdt\Leftrightarrow dx = \frac{2t}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}dt$

So integral convert into $\displaystyle \int t.\frac{2t}{\left(1-t^4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}dt$

So Integral is $\displaystyle 2\int\;t^2.\left(1-t^4\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dt$

Now Using $\displaystyle \bullet\; \int x^m.\left(a+bx^n\right)^p\;dx$

where $m\;,n\;,p$ are Rational no.

which is Integrable only when $\displaystyle \left(\frac{m+1}{n}\right)\in \mathbb{Z}$ or $\displaystyle \left\{\frac{m+1}{n}+p\right\}\in\mathbb{Z}$

Now here $\displaystyle 2\int\;t^2.\left(1-t^4\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dt$

$\displaystyle m = 2\;\;,a = 1\;\;,b = -1\;\;,n = 4\;\;,p = -\frac{1}{2}$

and $\displaystyle \left(\frac{2+1}{4}\right)\neq \mathbb{Z}$ or $\displaystyle \left(\frac{2+1}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\neq \mathbb{Z}$

So We can not integrate $\displaystyle \int\sqrt{\sin x}\;dx =2\int\;t^2.\left(1-t^4\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dt$ in terms of elementry function.

Answer (score 5):

Let $u=\sqrt{\sin x}$ ,

Then $x=\sin^{-1}u^2$

$dx=\dfrac{2u}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}du$

$\therefore\int\sqrt{\sin x}~dx$

$=\int\dfrac{2u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}du$

$=\int2u^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!u^{4n}}{4^n(n!)^2}du$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!u^{4n+2}}{2^{2n-1}(n!)^2}du$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!u^{4n+3}}{2^{2n-1}(n!)^2(4n+3)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!\sin^{2n+\frac{3}{2}}x}{2^{2n-1}(n!)^2(4n+3)}+C$