# when $\int x^m (a+bx^n)^p dx$ is elementary function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, elementary-functions

In one of the answers of the question  [Integration of sqrt Sin x dx](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469846/integration-of-sqrt-sin-x-dx), I saw something similiar to that:

$m,n,p \neq 0 \in \mathbb{Q}$

$\int x^m (a+bx^n)^p dx$ is elementary function $\implies$ $\frac{m+1}{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $\frac{m+1}{n} + p \in \mathbb{Z}$

is it true?

the other direction also true?

and where can I find a proof of this proposition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of Chebyshev.

A Google search for
"chebychev elementary functions integration"
turns up a number of relevant hits
including these:

http://www2.onu.edu/~m-caragiu.1/bonus_files/CHEBYSHE.pdf

http://www.rangevoting.org/MarchisottoZint.pdf

Also look up
"integration in finite terms".