# How do I calculate?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

How do I calculate cross-sectional area of this:

${r}=\sqrt{sin\theta} \, $, when $ 0 \le \theta \le \pi,$

Don't know what is the right answer but I have get that the area is 1. Is that right answer?

$\int_0^\pi\int_0^\sqrt{sin\theta}  r\, \textrm{d}r\textrm{d}\theta.$
Is this right?

Comment: As far as I know, the concept of cross-sectional area only applies to volumes, but in your problem it seems like you want to find the area under the curve $\sqrt{\sin{\theta}}$ bounded by $0$ from the left and $\pi$ from the right. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: For that, you need to know what the integral of $\int\sqrt{\sin{x}}\,dx$ is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469846/integration-of-sqrt-sin-x-dx or watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gImHfFKkVG8

Comment: Are you asked to find the area under that curve in polar coordinates?

Comment: This is a closed curve (sort of a squished ellipse), so I would presume that the OP is asked to find the area enclosed by the curve. That might be why "cross-sectional area" is mentioned.

Comment: Well, you do get the answer of $1$ square unit if you use the area formula for polar coordinates: $$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\left[r(\theta)\right]^2\,d\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and the answer I got:
$$\int_\limits{0}^\pi[\frac{r^2}2]_0^{\sqrt{\sin(\theta)}}]d\theta$$

$$\int_\limits{0}^\pi(\frac{\sin\theta}2)d\theta$$

$$[\frac{-\cos{\theta}}{2}]_0^\pi$$

$$-\frac{\cos\pi}{2}-
-\frac{\cos(0)}{2}=.5+.5=1$$