# Integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt {a^2-x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals

I need to evaluate the integral $$\int \frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt {a^2-x^2}}dx$$

I substituted $x=a\sin\theta$

Hence, the required integral is reduced to

$$\sqrt a \int \sqrt {\sin\theta}d\theta$$

However the integration of this function yields an elliptic function. Is there any way to integrate it so that it gives a more elementary function?

Comment: No---see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469846/integration-of-sqrt-sin-x-dx (of which this question is essentially a duplicate). More generally: Substituting gives the equivalent integral $$\int \frac{u^2 \,du}{\sqrt{a^2 - u^4}} ,$$ for but integrals of the form $$\int \frac{p(u) \,du}{\sqrt{q(u)}}$$ with $p, q$ polynomials and $q$ cubic or quartic, expressing the antiderivative requires elliptic functions or the equivalent to express, except in special cases that $p, q$ are related in certain ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antiderivative of a function is unique up to a constant. So, no, if you have found that the integral evaluates to an elliptic function, it will always evaluate to that elliptic function plus a constant no matter what method you use.

Answer (score 0):

if we find an analytic way to integrate what you are asking, wouldn't that automatically become a good way to integrate $\sqrt{\sin \theta}$? i don't think there is a good way to integrate elliptic functions...

Comment: I was wondering if integrating in another(more clever) way could yield a simpler function... or maybe since one method is returning an elliptic function, all other methods must also return some non-elementary functions?

Comment: @AnuragSaha i think so, otherwise if one would not, you would have an easy way to take a hard integral by converting it to your trick, which is what i wrote above