# Explanation of integral substitution without resorting to differentials

Tags: integration, substitution

Something very *mysterious and unexplained* happened in my calculus II class which is that the method of integration by substitution was presented in the language of differentials (which from my modest exposure to higher level math need to be *defined* and they haven't yet been).

While I understand that any function of the form $$\int f'(g(x)g'(x)$$ can be integrated as $f(g(x))$, I do not understand how substitution is used when the expression in the integral does not match the schema of $f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

The most readily available example (when I was researching this topic) I found here ([Integration of sqrt Sin x dx](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469846/integration-of-sqrt-sin-x-dx)) where they used $t^2 = \sin x$ as a substitution in $\int \sqrt{\sin(x)}$. Then they obtained that $dx = \frac{2t}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}$. I would think that this substitution cannot be made as there would need to be a $2t = 2\sqrt{\sin x}$ term in the original expression, corresponding to g'. It seems that the original expression can be algebraically manipulated so that even if a g' factor doesn't appear explicitly, it is effectively there. Why is this true: in my mind it is not consistent with the chain rule and I cannot find the intuition to *justify* it.

Comment: Be careful with your formalism, your expression for $dx$ makes no sense, as the left hand is a differential and the right hand is not.  There ought to be a factor of $dt$ on the right.  Again, since you are changing variables, it is bad form to write the integral with no differential at all.  You meant, I assume, $\int \sqrt {\sin x}\,dx$.  Then since you have an equivalent expression for $dx$ you are free to substitute it for $dx$.

Comment: As to the original form for the substitution, in which you again forget to write the $dx$, this is just the chain rule.  One has $\frac {d}{dx} f\circ g(x)=f'(g(x))\times g'(x)$ as desired.

Comment: Should say:  later on, one does get a proper definition of differentials, though at first pass it's typical to just use them as a formal short hand.

Comment: Thank you. I understand how this is just the chain rule. Should I delete the question now.