# Integral with square root + Trig

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{-3 \sin(x) - 3 \cos(x) + 5} ~~dx$$

I tried to use substitution:

$$ u = -3 \sin(x) -3 \cos(x) + 5 \\ du = -3 \cos(x) + 3 \sin(x) $$

But because $ ( \cos(x) )' = - \sin(x)$ it does not work that well (the signs are now flipped...)

I even tried to change the $\cos(x)$ into $\sin( x - \frac{\pi}{2} )$ but it didn't get me very far..

I also tried using this online tool: https://www.integral-calculator.com/
And it couldn't find the anti-derivative, but only gave the answer of:

$$ \approx 5.1363$$

I would appreciate your help, really any way possible to solve this ugly question would be appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a source for this? Is there good reason to believe it has a closed-form solution?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I actually don't know except it is one of many tasks I have, and also one that is similar: $ \int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{ -2 \sin(x) -2 \cos(x) + 3}  ~~ dx $

Comment: Not elementary [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B5+-+3*Sin%5Bx%5D+-+3*Cos%5Bx%5D%5D%2C+x%5D)

Comment: @stackomeow rewrite $-3\sin(x)-3\cos(x)+5$ as $5-3\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4)$ using a sum identify. Then take a look at this [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1472108/843441).

Comment: Finally done and "simple" ! Cheers

Comment: I made it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to @Andrew's comment make
$$\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt{2} \cos \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)=\sqrt{2} \left(1-2 \sin ^2\left(\frac{x }{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right)$$ This makes
$$5-3\sin(x)-3\cos(x)=(5-3 \sqrt{2})+6 \sqrt{2} \sin ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi }{8}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{5-3\sin(x)-3\cos(x)}=a\,\sqrt{1+k\sin ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi }{8}\right)}$$ with $$a=\sqrt{5-3 \sqrt{2}}\qquad \text{and}\qquad k=\frac{6(6+5 \sqrt{2})}{7} $$

Now, let $\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi }{8}=t$ that is to say $x=2t+\frac{\pi }{4}$ to make the antiderivative
$$I=2a \int  \sqrt{1+k \sin^2 (t)}\,dt =2a\,E(t|-k)$$ where appears the elliptic integral  on fthe first kind.

Back to $x$, $a$ and $k$, using the bounds and simplifying, we the have

$$\color{red}{\int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{5-3 \sin(x) - 3 \cos(x) }\,dx =}$$
$$\color{red}{2 \sqrt{5-3 \sqrt{2}} \left(E\left(\frac{\pi }{8}|-\frac{6\left(6+5
   \sqrt{2}\right)}{7} \right)+E\left(\frac{3 \pi }{8}|-\frac{6\left(6+5
   \sqrt{2}\right)}{7} \right)\right)}$$ which is
$$5.1363328412422184497730638111478712316615873410060$$

Comment: Great answer, thank you sir!

Comment: What is the E function?

Comment: @BenjaminWang. $E(.)$ is the elliptic integral on fthe first kind